# inline divs with fixed headers / titles

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS Code:

```
.homeBoxes {
    width: 49%;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    min-height:300px;
    max-height:350px;
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.title {
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    padding:2px;
    font-size:20px;
    background-color:#f36f25;
}
```

i want the title to be fixed within the `.homeBoxes` div and 100% (not displaying the scroll bar to the right of the title)

only to be fixed within the div and not on the whole page

http://jsfiddle.net/f3z3h/1/

Comment: overflow: hidden; Try this.. you have given min-height and max height. Take a look at that.. [Look here](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/f3z3h/3/)

Comment: where would i try that?

Comment: Take a look at my edit

Comment: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/f3z3h/3/)

Comment: if you make that an answer i will mark it for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/f3z3h/3/)

Set overflow property.

```
.homeBoxes 
{
 width: 49%;
 display:inline;
 float:left;
 overflow-y:scroll;
 min-height:300px;
 max-height:350px;
 margin-right:5px;
 margin-left:5px;
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you want scrolling to the content , specify overflow:auto or scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f3z3h/5/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="homeBoxes_container">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
    <div class="homeBoxes">TEXT</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.homeBoxes_container {
    clear:both;
    width: 49%;
     min-height:300px;
    max-height:350px;
}
.homeBoxes {
    width:100%;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    overflow-y:scroll;   
    margin-right:5px;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
     min-height:300px;
    max-height:350px;
}
```